# How to use UrlRewriteFilter to remove ".jsp" from a url with query string

Tags: url-rewriting

For some reason, I need to remove ".jsp" from a Url with query string in a Spring MVC project, using **UrlRewriteFilter**.

For example, I want to change

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/project.jsp?m_product=GA&m_code1=QULQ2U
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/project?m_product=GA&m_code1=QULQ2U
```

I have tried various rules, but no success.

For example, when I set the rule as

```
<rule>
    <from>/admin/project.jsp?(.+)</from>
    <to type="redirect">/admin/project?$1</to>
</rule>
```

UrlRewriteFilter will change

```
admin/project.jsp?m_product=GA&m_code1=QULQ2U
```

to

```
admin/project?p
```

When I use the following rule to escape the question mark before the query string

```
<rule>
    <from>/admin/project.jsp\?(.+)</from>
    <to type="redirect">/admin/project?$1</to>
</rule>
```

UrlRewriteFilter will not rewrite the URL.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: As I understand by default `<from>` is working with URL path only (query string is not included -- you need to have `<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">` or use `<condition type ="query-string">` to work with query strings). Therefore first rule will work any way, as `?` makes previous letter `p` (in `jsp`) optional. In second rule you made `?` required character -- it has to be always present. Try `(\?(.+))?` instead of `\?(.+)` and replace `$1` by `$2`. (**P.S.** The are just general ideas, i'm not really familiar with UrlRewriteFilter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the helps.

The problem is Solved!

To achieve the goal, I changed the rule to

```
<rule>
    <from>/admin/project.jsp(.*)</from>
    <to type="forward">/project</to>
</rule>
```

The trick is to replace redirect to forward.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the extension(.jsp) from project using Tuckey url re-writing filter then it may helpful for you.

```
From
    http://locatohost:8080/urlrewrite/feedback.jsp 
To
    http://locatohost:8080/urlrewrite/feedback
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" 
"http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
  <rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z]+)$</from>
    <to>/$1.jsp</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

And if you want to vise-versa(means you want to remove .jsp from page hyperlinks)then use below rule

```
  <outbound-rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z]+)(.(jsp|jspx))$</from>
    <to>$1</to>
  </outbound-rule>
```

so that when you use

```
<LI><A href="complaints.htm">Complaints</A></LI>
```

then it will be written in page as

```
<LI><A href="complaints">Complaints</A></LI>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the [OCPsoft Rewrite | URLRewriteFilter](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/), this would be as simple as specifying one rule:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/admin/project")
             .to("/admin/project.jsp")
             .withInboundCorrection());
```

This handles both the inbound Forward, the outbound HTML replacement, and also redirects from the old .jsp URL to the new /admin/project URL if someone asks for the old URL, or has an old bookmark.

The query-string is automatically handled for you, so no need to worry about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<rule>
  <from>/admin/project\.jsp\?(.+)</from>
  <to type="redirect">/admin/project?$1</to>
</rule>
```

As a general rule, you should rather use a controller for such a task and let the crappy JSP do what it is supposed to do: VIEW